# Use i18n on multiselect widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, widget

I'm new to JS/Jquery and I'm using the [jquery multiselect plugin](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) in my app.

But i don't find how set and translate the widget with the i18n files supplieds with the master package from github.

Anyone already used this plugin and know how to set the i18n files? It's in a external way of the widget? Can show me how?

Comment: Add a reference to the script with the localization you want.

Comment: <script src="{dir}/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="{dir}/i18n/jquery.multiselect.fr.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks, has i said I'm pretty noob :/ Can you post your comment has the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to the script with the localization you want:

```
<script src="{dir}/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="{dir}/i18n/jquery.multiselect.fr.js"></script>
```